# Is there an easier way to get start of current day time than this?

Tags: java, datetime, groovy, calendar

I basically want to get zero or beginning hour for currrent day.

```
def today = Calendar.instance
today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
println today // Mon Mar 15 00:00:00 SGT 2010
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not simpler than the other solutions, but less lines:

```
def now = new GregorianCalendar()
def today = new GregorianCalendar(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
println today.getTime()
```

Comment: This is indeed shorter than the rest of the proposed solutions. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`clearTime()` function](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3374) of [`Calendar`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Calendar.html) in Groovy:

```
def calendar = Calendar.instance
calendar.with {
  clearTime()
  println time
}
```

> It'd be nice to have a convenience method that clears the time portion of a `java.util.Date` and/or `java.util.Calendar`.
>   There are numerous use cases where it makes sense to compare month/day/year only portions of a calendar or date. Essentially, it would perform the following on Calendar:

```
void clearTime() {
    clear(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    clear(Calendar.HOUR)
    clear(Calendar.MINUTE)
    clear(Calendar.SECOND)
    clear(Calendar.MILLISECOND) 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be nice to have to have such a method. But if you can settle for a short function then here's mine:

```
def startOfDay(t) {
    tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    t +=tz.getOffset(t);
    t -= (t % 86400000);
    t-tz.getOffset(t);
}

print new Date(startOfDay(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Groovy date](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN0545-Dates) documentation, it seems that it's the optimal way.

However, using Groovy [with](http://javajeff.blogspot.com/2008/11/getting-groovy-with-with.html) keyword, you can compress a little your statements

```
def today = Calendar.instance
with(today) {
    set Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0
    set Calendar.MINUTE, 0
    set Calendar.SECOND, 0
}
println today // Mon Mar 15 00:00:00 SGT 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is the best way, or indeed correct (not sure if timezone issues will arise from this), but it could work for simple use cases:

**Start of day**

```
def today = new Date()
def start = today.clearTime()
```

**End of day**

```
def today = new Date()
def eod

use (TimeCategory) {
    eod = today.clearTime() + 1.day - 1.millisecond
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Java 8 use java.time solution:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIN);
ldt.toString();
```