# Java, creating two identical zip files if content are the same

Tags: java, zip

I have this, which works fine for zipping and unzipping:

```
    public static final String SLASH = "/";
    public static void zip(int level, File zipfile, File... files) throws IOException {
            try (FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(zipfile); ZipOutputStream zo = new ZipOutputStream(fo)) {
                    zo.setLevel(level);

                    for (File file : files) {
                            zip("", file, zo);
                    }

                    zo.flush();
                    zo.finish();
                    zo.close();

                    // !!!!!!!! Tried these !!!!!!!!!
                    long time = Cal.date(1970, Cal.Month.JANUARY, 1).getTime();
                    zipfile.setLastModified(time);
                    Files.setAttribute(zipfile.toPath(), "lastAccessTime", FileTime.fromMillis(time) );
            }
    }

    public static File unzip(File zipfile, File to) throws IOException {
            ZipFile                         filezipped = new ZipFile( zipfile );
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries    = filezipped.entries( ) ;

            while ( entries.hasMoreElements() ) {

                    ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement( )             ;
                    File     file     = new File( to, zipEntry.getName( ) );

                    if ( zipEntry.isDirectory() ) {
                            file.mkdirs();
                    }
                    else {
                            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                            try ( InputStream in = filezipped.getInputStream(zipEntry) ) {
                                    Files.copy( in, file.toPath() );
                            }
                    }
            }

            return zipfile;
    }

    private static void zip(String base, File file, ZipOutputStream zo) throws IOException {
            String path   = base + file.getName();
            if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
                    path += SLASH;

                    zo.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry(path) );

                    for (File ff : file.listFiles()) {
                            zip(path, ff, zo);
                    }

                    zo.closeEntry();

            } else {
                    zo.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry(path) );

                    Files.copy(file.toPath(), zo);

                    zo.closeEntry();
            }
    }
```

However, the zip file will have a different checksum even though the content of the file is unchanged. This is a problem when committing the files using git.

**How can I ensure that the zipped file stays the same every time unless content has changed?**

Comment: Are there changes in the timestamps of the files that you're zipping?

Comment: Hmm, no. But it made me think regarding the unzipping. I am unzipping and then zipping again. Possibly my unzipping is what is causing the header mismatch. I will try.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen no, i tried to change the files timestamp as well, still seesm to generate a different md5

Comment: Even when setting the time on the `ZipEntry` objects as in my answer below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamp on the ZIP file itself shouldn't matter, but try setting the last modification time of the ZIP entries to a constant value:

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(path);
entry.setTime(0);

zo.putNextEntry(entry);
```

See the [`setTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#setTime(long)) JavaDoc for more info.

---

**Update**

The above should indeed do the trick, provided the content and order of your entries is identical. I took a look at the source code for `ZipOutputStream`, and found the following in the `putNextEntry` method:

```
if (e.time == -1) {
    e.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

So setting the `time` to 0 before adding the entry to the stream should prevent it from being overwritten, and keep your content constant.

Comment: Awesome, you are the man! I noticed that there are zipEntry.setCreationTime, setLastAccessTime, and setAccessTime as well. I haven't used them but only setTime(0).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what your `Cal` class is doing, but I suspect that internally it's creating a `Calendar` instance and setting the date fields. You should be aware that if you do this then it will still end up with the current time of day, not 00:00! So you are most likely *not* getting the same timestamp each time.

I'd just try

```
long time = 0;
```

rather than mucking about with calendar instances.

Comment: I do Calendar.getInstance().get(year, month, day). I believe this is ok. Robbys answer seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @SecretService Glad you got it sorted. Do you mean `.set`? That is def not OK: it will return the date you chose but the *current* time. You need a `.clear()` first.

Comment: Yeah, tricky business. I am doing cal.get(int, int, int); I believe this returns the start of the day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445962/is-there-an-easier-way-to-get-start-of-current-day-time-than-this

Comment: @SecretService I can't see anything in that question or in the Javadoc to suggest there's a three-valued `.get(int, int, int)`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant set! :)